# Clone a bootable M2-SSD (Win10) to a new M2-SDD-Volume containing (Win11)

Tags: boot, ssd, windows-11, clone, disk-image

I have an HP laptop (1) with Windows 11 22H2 installed and another HP laptop (2) with Windows 10.
Would it be possible to clone/image the windows 10 M2-ssd to be another bootable volume on the Windows 11 Laptop (1)?

What i want to achieve is is for the Laptop (1) to prompt when it boot whether it should use win-11 (existing) or win-10 (the clone/image).

Thanks

Comment: Possible but should be strongly discouraged. Why don't you simply install Windows 10 as a dual-boot?

Comment: Or run Windows 10 as a VM.  I do this and it works great and simultaneously.

Comment: Both laptops are for 2 different entities.... each is on different domain. i don't want to carry both laptop with me. IT will reject to activate and enroll non assets to the domain.